# ServiceMix: logmessage "Cannot start the broker"

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, apache-servicemix

I run servicemix 6.1.0 for a few days now. Camel routes with file- and jdbc endpoints work - cool stuff.

Now i want to add activemq. When i install servicemix from scratch everything looks fine - jms works.

But now i see exceptions in the logfile at startup and the command `karaf@root>activemq:list` returns nothing.

Here is a portion of the logfile:

```
...
2015-12-11 10:43:35,081 | INFO  | ctivemq.server]) | PListStoreImpl                   | 176 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.12.1 | PListStore:[C:\CAD_JOBS\apache-servicemix-6.1.0\data\amq-broker\amq-broker\tmp_storage] started
2015-12-11 10:43:35,084 | INFO  | ctivemq.server]) | ActiveMQServiceFactory$1         | 161 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context - 3.2.14.RELEASE_1 | Publishing application context as OSGi service with properties {org.springframework.context.service.name=org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi, Bundle-SymbolicName=org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi, Bundle-Version=5.12.1}
2015-12-11 10:43:35,093 | ERROR | ctivemq.server]) | configadmin                      | 6 - org.apache.felix.configadmin - 1.8.4 | [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedServiceFactory, id=813, bundle=176/mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-osgi/5.12.1]: Updating configuration org.apache.activemq.server.24d13a82-a253-4d1e-8355-bcbf0fff6927 caused a problem: Cannot start the broker
org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationException: null : Cannot start the broker
    at org.apache.activemq.osgi.ActiveMQServiceFactory.updated(ActiveMQServiceFactory.java:120)[176:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.12.1]
    at Proxye6b76768_a1ce_4232_9f62_ee376293401b.updated(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.updated(ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.java:159)[6:org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.8.4]
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.provideConfiguration(ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.java:93)[6:org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.8.4]
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.ConfigurationManager$ManagedServiceFactoryUpdate.provide(ConfigurationManager.java:1597)[6:org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.8.4]
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.ConfigurationManager$ManagedServiceFactoryUpdate.run(ConfigurationManager.java:1540)[6:org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.8.4]
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.UpdateThread.run(UpdateThread.java:103)[6:org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.8.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)[:1.7.0_17]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service object is not an instance of "org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable".
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:3386)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:346)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractOsgiBundleApplicationContext.publishContextAsOsgiServiceIfNecessary(AbstractOsgiBundleApplicationContext.java:344)[165:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractOsgiBundleApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractOsgiBundleApplicationContext.java:237)[165:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)[161:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$301(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:69)[165:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:186)[165:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)[165:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.normalRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:182)[165:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$NoDependenciesWaitRefreshExecutor.refresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:89)[165:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:175)[165:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.osgi.ActiveMQServiceFactory.updated(ActiveMQServiceFactory.java:102)[176:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.12.1]
    ... 7 more
2015-12-11 10:43:35,095 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 15 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.4 | Bundle org.apache.servicemix.activemq.service/6.1.0 is waiting for dependencies [(objectClass=javax.transaction.TransactionManager)]
2015-12-11 10:43:35,101 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 15 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.4 | Bundle org.apache.servicemix.activemq.camel/6.1.0 is waiting for dependencies [(&(&(transacted=false)(name=default-cf))(objectClass=javax.jms.ConnectionFactory))]
2015-12-11 10:43:35,104 | INFO  | FelixStartLevel  | CXFActivator                     | 92 - org.apache.cxf.cxf-core - 3.1.4 | Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.camel.camel-cxf-transport (231) [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.transport.CamelTransportFactory]
...
```

The questions are: Whats going wrong and why and how to fix the problem?
Thx for your time.

Comment: You write 'When i install servicemix from scratch everything looks fine - jms works.' Does it mean that the broker is ok after you install a fresh ServiceMix?

Comment: Yes, it works after a fresh unpack. There are messages in the queue after running a route with a jms-endpoint. I assume i have done something that causes activemq to fail at restart. But i think that was only stuff like `install camel-jdbc` and something like that. I'm lost...

Comment: I tried to install some jpa, jdbc, transaction features and it looks ok. It would be nice if you could try to reproduce the problem starting with fresh installation to check which feature breaks the broker

Answer (score 2):

You could check that you have not installed any Spring 4.x features or JARs.
You can see installed features with

feature:list

Similar issue happened when installed spring-jdbc in Servicemix 6.1.0  (downloaded Servicemix zip from the site)

feature:install spring-jdbc (this causes ActiveMQ to broke)

but

feature:install spring-jdbc/3.2.14.RELEASE_1 (ActiveMQ still works).

I suspect that installing spring 4.x JARs causes someone to see too new JARs, but I didn't investigate this further.

feature:install camel-sql

installs spring-jdbc 3.2.14.RELEASE_1 (in SMX 6.1.0)